# Angular, Inject an Input from a Component into my header

Tags: javascript, angular, components, inject, ng-content

I want for my `Pages` induvidually to inject different components from other `Pages/Components` into the `header`. For example I want to inject an `Input` search Field from my `content-component` into my `header` Component. I tried with `ng-Content`, but this only duplicates my `header` in my `HTML`. The problem is my `header` is not in each `Component` individually, its in my `app.component`.

**My Header Component:**

```
<div class="header__sub">
<div class="header__title header__title--sub">
    <h2 class="title title--medium">{{ subtitle }}</h2>
</div>
<div class="header__search">
    <!-- Here should be my Input field -->
    <ng-content></ng-content>
</div>
```

**Component from I want to inject the input field:**

```
<app-header>
   <mat-form-field>
        <input matInput (keyup)="applyFilter($event.target.value)" placeholder="Search" />
   </mat-form-field>
</app-header>  
 ....
```

**App-Component.html:**

```
<mat-drawer-content>
    // The header
    <app-header-sub>
    </app-header-sub>
    <div class="content__inner">
        // My Content
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </div>
</mat-drawer-content>
```

How can I inject from each Component individually a different tag into the `header` (with functionalities)?

Comment: You don't. Use a service (@Injectable) for that. Inject the service into your component and into your header. Set the value on your service and retrieve it in your header.

Answer (score 1):

You can use it like that:

Child component

```
<div class="header">
  <ng-content select="[name]"></ng-content>
<div>
```

Parent component

```
<app-header>
  <div name>Hello World</div>
</app-header>
```

Demo for your reference: https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-content-select-attribute

Or look here: [Multiple ng-content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52638718/multiple-ng-content)