# Angular component with multiple HTML parts

Tags: angular

I would like to create a dialog component with multiple HTML parts:

```
<my-dialog>
    <content>
        Here is first HTML content
    </content>
    <buttons>
        Here is second HTML content with a list of button HTML elements
    </buttons>
</my-dialog>
```

My question is if the `my-dialog` component can have the `content` and `buttons` parts directly as some templates parts or whether I need to create separate components for `content` and `buttons` parts.

**Update**:
This question can be closed, as duplicate of [Multiple ng-content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52638718/multiple-ng-content).

Comment: @cloned My question is, if the `my-dialog` component can have the `content` and `buttons` parts directly as some templates parts or whether I need to create separate components for `content` and `buttons`.

Comment: You can do it however you like. Whatever makes most sense for your application and whatever gives you the best reusability in your project.

Comment: What about [hidden] or ngIf to hide or show some content based on some events ?

Comment: I am looking for a component with multiple `ng-content`, as shown here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52638718/multiple-ng-content. Sorry, I did not know how to name the problem better, I am new to Angular.